# Check if an element is present in an array that is attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm using Lodash and I want to check if an element is present inside an array that is actually a property (in my case "feature") of an object that is itself part of an array. I tried with _.some and _.find but I didn't succeed

```
const element = 'Hello'
class Example {
    constructor {}

  async featuresCheck () {
    this.Array = [
      { name: something
       surname: somethingelse
       features:[element, ...]
     }, 
    ]

    if (_.some(this.Array,{features:element})){
      console.log('element included')
    } else {
      console.log('element not included')
    }
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori)'s answer is correct. Here is an added example using [lodash.some](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.some).

```js
const element = 'Hello';

const array = [{
  name: 'foo',
  features: [element, 'bar']
}, {
  name: 'baz',
  features: []
}];

const doesFeatureExist = (requiredFeature) => _.some(array, (object) => _.some(object.features, (feature) => feature === requiredFeature));

console.log(doesFeatureExist(element));
console.log(doesFeatureExist('bar'));
console.log(doesFeatureExist('foo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:**
Here's how you can achieve your desired result with a JS class:

```js
const element = 'Hello'

class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.array = [{
      name: 'foo',
      features: [element, 'bar']
    }, {
      name: 'baz',
      features: []
    }];
  }

  featuresCheck(requiredFeature) {
    if (_.some(this.array, (object) => _.some(object.features, (feature) => feature === requiredFeature))) {
      console.log('element included')
    } else {
      console.log('element not included')
    }

  }
}

const example = new Example();

example.featuresCheck(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I changed the code snippet because I'm in a class

Answer (score 0):

To check if one exists, use nested `Array.some()` (or `_.some()`) calls. To find the object, use `Array.find()` with `Array.some()`:

```js
const element = 'Hello'

const arr = [
 { features:['not hello'] }, 
 { features:['Hello'] }, 
]

const exists = arr.some(o => o.features.some(el => el === element))
const item = arr.find(o => o.features.some(el => el === element))

console.log('exists: ', exists)
console.log('item: ', item)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm in a javascript class, so when I run your code it gives me the TypeError "Cannot set property 'features' of undefined"

Comment: Since the code here doesn't set anything, you're problem doing something wrong. Run the snippet to see that it works, and then see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Drun if you are using a class you should update the code snippet in your question.

Comment: Ok I did it, please have a look now